# Electron Forge Typescript+Webpack Boilerplate doesn't generate source maps for the renderer script

Tags: electron, electron-forge

The source maps are generated only for the main process script, but not for the renderer process script. If the project is compiled via tsc source maps are generated.

Link to the docs of the boilerplate: https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template

How to install the boilerplate: `npx create-electron-app my-new-app --template=typescript-webpack`

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the source maps aren't produced for the renderer process?  If it's using webpack, the source map might be concatenated onto the end of the renderer process' index.js file...